# Explain quosure to a dummy

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, quosure

I'm trying to make a function that will produce a plot when given passed a variable to plot.
The variable is selected from a dropdown - hence `aes_string`.

```
make_plot <- function(data, plot_var) {
          plot_var <- enquo(plot_var)
          ggplot(data) +
            aes_string(x = !!plot_var) +
            geom_area(alpha = 0.5)
          }
        
make_plot(my_data, variable_i_want_to_plot)
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Quosures can only be unquoted within a quasiquotation context.
# Bad: list(!!myquosure) # Good: dplyr::mutate(data, !!myquosure)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aes_string` has been deprecated. Try this function :

```
make_plot <- function(data, plot_var) {
  ggplot(data) + aes(x = .data[[plot_var]]) + geom_area(alpha = 0.5)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `aes_string` by `aes`.

`aes_string` was the *old* way of using computed variables with ‘ggplot2’. Quosures (used inside a regular `aes` call) are the new way. You can’t mix the two.

Answer (score 0):

We can convert the string to `sym`bol and use `!!`

```
make_plot <- function(data, plot_var) {
       ggplot(data,  aes(x = !! rlang::sym(plot_var)) + geom_area(alpha = 0.5)
  }
```